# Смена класса таблицы без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем дня

[Код](http://jsfiddle.net/6X72Q/6/)

Есть Таблица, у ней class. По пришествию 3 секунд JS скриптом можно его сменить на другой. Можно ли заменять class,  не 1 раз, а несколько? (допустим 6-7). Загрузилась страница, и через определенное время стиль постепенно меняется. Помогите решить данный вопрос

Comment: setInterval()

Comment: так он же будет обновлять, а не заменять? я имел ввиду 1 заменить на второе, потом на третье, потом на 4е...

Comment: что установите в теле функции интервала, то и будет делать,

...
var currentClass = $('#table').attr('class');
$('#table').removeClass(currentClass).addClass(newClass);
...

Comment: дайте влепить акцепт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если беж jquery, то так:

```
var classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5']

var table = document.getElementById('mytable') // таблицы должен быть id="mytable"

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (classes.length) {
        table.className = classes.shift();                
    } 
    else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    } 
}, 3000);
```